# Выбор метода интерполяции и экстраполяции

Tags: python, scipy

Есть задача выбора аккумуляторной батареи по требуемому времени работы и мощности.
Первый шаг — рассчитать мощность по заданному времени исходя из таблицы разрядных характеристик.
Для этого нужно интерполировать данные в заданном диапазоне и экстраполировать за пределами имеющихся данных. У меня два вопроса.

1. Какой из методов интерполяции даст наиболее точный результат?
2. Как экстраполировать данные? Метод UnivariateSpline дает неадекватные результаты. При k=1 линейно уходит в отрицательные значения, чего не может быть. При k>=2 круто улетает вверх.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

values = [
  [5, 5016],
  [8, 4452.6],
  [10,  3600.0],
  [15,  3018.0],
  [20,  2424.0],
  [30,  1914.0],
  [60,  1080.0],
  [90,  742.2]
    ]
data = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['time','power'])

xp = data.loc[:, 'time']
yp = data.loc[:, 'power']

#display(xp)

# 1 способ интерполяции (кусочно-линейная)
x1 = 45
t1 = np.interp(x1, xp, yp)
print(t1)
# 2 способ интерполяции (kind=2 - параболическая)
f = interpolate.interp1d(xp, yp, kind=2)
t2 = f(x1)
print(t2)
xr = np.linspace(5,90,25)

# Экстраполяция
extrapolator = UnivariateSpline(xp, yp, k=2)
print(extrapolator(180))

# plt.axes(ylim=(t1-800,t1+500),xlim=(x1-10,x1+30))
plt.plot(xp,yp, 'p')
plt.plot(xp,yp, 'r')
plt.plot(x1,t1, 'x')
plt.plot(x1,t2, 'rx')
plt.plot(xr,f(xr))
xs = np.linspace(5,180,25)
plt.plot(xs, extrapolator(xs), '-')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD.**

Тут скорее всего будет экспоненциальная зависимость. Попробовал такой вариант:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
  return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xp, yp)
plt.plot(xs, func(xs, *popt), 'r-')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это больше похоже на правду, но получается слишком медленное затухание функции. Что касается физической модели. То тут вряд ли будет сигмоида, скорее экспоненциальная зависимость.

Семейство кривых при разряде постоянной мощностью.
[image: Семейство кривых]

Comment: Неверно выбрана функция экстраполяции. тут нужно что-то близкое к 1/x, а никак не сплайн.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта задача не решается экстраполяцией. Необходимо сначала из физических соображений подобрать функцию разряда, и только после того, как выбрана физическая модель, аппроксимировать параметры модели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот график разряда в зависимости от времени и температуры. Видно невооруженным глазом, что никакие сплайны, интерполяционные полиномы и прочие математические трюки не в состоянии предсказать падение тока вблизи максимального разряда.

Если вы не знаете физическую модель явления, то нужно что-то придумать. Например, ткнуть пальцем в потолок и провозгласить: "Функция разряда от времени должна быть обратной сигмоидной".

Ткнув пальцем второй раз, можно выбрать из всех сигмодных обратную логистическую: `p = pwr_avg + theta*np.log(t_max/t - 1)`

У неё вот такой график:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для подбора параметров есть функция [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as spo

values = np.array([
  [5, 5016],
  [8, 4452.6],
  [10,  3600.0],
  [15,  3018.0],
  [20,  2424.0],
  [30,  1914.0],
  [60,  1080.0],
  [90,  742.2]
    ])

def model2(t, theta, t_max, pwr_avg, dt=0):
    tau = t+dt
    return pwr_avg + theta*np.log(t_max/tau-1)

params, pcov = spo.curve_fit(model2, values[:,0], values[:,1], 
                             p0=(1000, 200, 600, 10), maxfev=10000,
                             bounds=((800,200,400,0), (2000,2000,1000, 100)))

p = np.linspace(0,2000, 1000)
plt.plot(values[:,0], values[:,1])
plt.plot(p, model2(p, *params))
```

Результат вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятное дело, приближение корявое, но ведь и модель взята с потолка. Чем лучше физическая модель, тем лучше результат.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться с этой функцией. В своем вопросе добавил информацию по физической модели. На приведенном вами графике зависимость падения напряжения, а требуется зависимость мощности от времени.

Comment: @Alexey пожалуйста, не принимайте сигмоидную функцию так близко к сердцу! Я её взял с потолка всего лишь как иллюстрацию. Вам же требуется посмотреть в литературе физические модели и выбрать функцию из предложенных. Если таких нет, то сразу скажу, что по одной кривой подбирать формулу нельзя. Нужно брать данные по нескольким режимам разряда и подгонять по ним.